# Orthonormal family in $L^{2}([0,2\pi])$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, orthogonality

I'm looking to show that this family of vectors defined in this picture are orthonormal with respect to the $L^2$ inner product. I have managed to show they are orthogonal however end up finding their lengths to be $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ rather than 1. I'm sure I'm making a simple error here but I can't see it.[image]

Comment: Whether this is right depends on how the norm is "normaliized". People define that norm differently. If the definition is $||f||_2^2=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f(t)|^2$ then the functions $e^{ikt}$ are orthonormal; if there's some other constant in front of the integral then you need a different constant in the definition of $e_k$.

So, nobody can  tell whether you're right and if not what your error is until you give us more information.

Comment: The norm being used is the one induced by this inner product, $\langle f,g\rangle=$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\overline{g(x)} dx$. Does this not give an orthonormal family?

Comment: No, with that inner product and your definition of $e_k$ you're right, $||e_k||_2\ne1$. You should figure out what the $frac1{2\pi}$ should be replaced by in the definition of $e_k$.